# Power BI Burndown chart using date columns

Tags: powerbi

Trying to create a burndown chart in Power BI using data from an Excel Workbook, how do I either transform the data or use the data as is with visualizations and measures/columns (see example below)?

Have attempted to use the data as is (see example) with a "Line and Clustered Column Chart" but the best I can do is to show the number of instances that happened on the specific dates.

ID      Sector          Date

1       Sector1        6/1/2019

2       Sector1        6/7/2019

3       Sector1        6/7/2019

4       Sector1

5       Sector2

6       Sector2        6/1/2019

The results would show:
Sector1 starting before 6/1 with a count of 4 (there are 4 entries in the table for Sector1 as a total)

Then show the value decreasing to 3 on 6/1 (since there is 1 entry on that date for Sector1)

Followed by the value decreasing to 1 on 6/7 (there are 2 entries for Sector1 with that date)

While at it, would also like to plot a burndown line for both Sector1 & Sector2 on the same visualization. Any thoughts on how this can be accomplished?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To be able to do this, you need an order in your row data, can I assume the ID is the correct order, meaning it will increase each time and Dates are following this order?

Comment: No, I'm trying to use the date as the "order" and show the date on the axis of the visualization. The rows that don't have a date are not decremented from the total (which could simply be the Count of IDs.

Answer (score 0):

First we need to know the value for each sector on that particular date, so add a column to your table:

```
Value = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Sector Burndown');
    FILTER('Sector Burndown';
        'Sector Burndown'[Sector] = EARLIER('Sector Burndown'[Sector]) && 'Sector Burndown'[Date] >= EARLIER('Sector Burndown'[Date])))
```

As you want to have a value of 4 in the burndown, I added a new column called BurnDate, it sets the blank dates one week before the minimum vlaue in the table:

```
BurnDate = 
var weekbefore = MIN('Sector Burndown'[Date]) -7
return if (ISBLANK('Sector Burndown'[Date]); weekbefore; 'Sector Burndown'[Date])
```

Your table looks like:
[image]

Based on this you can make your burndown: Note that you have to set the BurnDate to the value and not the Hierarchy (Axis) & You ned to take the average of the value, not the sum. Enjoy!

[image]